# I have a database diagram in Microsoft Visio how can i import it to Sql Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, visio

I have done a database diagram in Microsoft Visio but I don't know how to import it to Sql Server 2005?

By the way, which is the best tool you think you can use to do database diagrams, and that allows you to import it to Sql Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar thread is here: http://www.linkedin.com/answers/technology/software-development/TCH_SFT/291114-19420164?browseCategory=TCH_SFT

Reproduced here:

> > So long as you have the Enterprise Architecture version of Visio, all you have to do is click: Database -> Generate.
> >
> > From there you can generate the DDL and even create a new database.
> >
> > Once you have the DDL you will have to use a query window to open the file and then so long as you have access to create a new schema and tables, etc... you can create your new database.

In my openion Microsoft Visio is the best which works with Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: This is external program to visio? Could you provide a URL to look at it?

Comment: @netadictos - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/HA011496961033.aspx should provide you the info you need about the Enterprise Architect version

Answer (score 0):

i'm not 100% sure you can import database diagrams from vision into sql server 2005

sql server 2005 has a neat built-in database diagram tool that actually builds the tables and relationships as you build them in the diagram.